# Migration error with wagtail 2.0

Tags: django, wagtail

Hi i'm trying to upgrade to wagtail 2.0. I have dealt with a series of errors but I can't get past this one which occurs on migration:

```
  File "/Users/tim/wagtailcmsdemo/home/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 17, in Migration
    ('page_ptr', models.OneToOneField(parent_link=True, auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='wagtailcore.Page')),
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Tim

Full console error:

> (wagtail-isa) MacBook-Air:wagtailcmsdemo tim$ ./manage.py
>   makemigrations Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "./manage.py", line 10, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/Users/tim/Virtualenvs/wagtail-isa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 371, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/Users/tim/Virtualenvs/wagtail-isa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 365, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/Users/tim/Virtualenvs/wagtail-isa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 288, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/Users/tim/Virtualenvs/wagtail-isa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 335, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/Users/tim/Virtualenvs/wagtail-isa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py",
>   line 78, in handle
>       loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)   File "/Users/tim/Virtualenvs/wagtail-isa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
>   line 49, in **init**
>       self.build_graph()   File "/Users/tim/Virtualenvs/wagtail-isa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
>   line 200, in build_graph
>       self.load_disk()   File "/Users/tim/Virtualenvs/wagtail-isa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
>   line 109, in load_disk
>       migration_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))   File
>   "/Users/tim/Virtualenvs/wagtail-isa/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 978, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 961, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 655, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 678, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 205, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "/Users/tim/wagtailcmsdemo/home/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 7,
>   in 
>       class Migration(migrations.Migration):   File "/Users/tim/wagtailcmsdemo/home/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 17,
>   in Migration
>       ('page_ptr', models.OneToOneField(parent_link=True, auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False,
>   to='wagtailcore.Page')), TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required
>   positional argument: 'on_delete'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by [docs of wagtail v2.0.1 compatibility](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/v2.0.1/README.rst#compatibility)

> Wagtail supports Django 1.11.x and 2.0 on Python 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6. Supported database backends are PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite.

but you try to use Django >= 1.11
and by [doc django ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) for version 1.11

> (on_delete isn’t actually required, but not providing it gives a deprecation warning. It will be required in Django 2.0.)

Comment: @TimK is it help you?

Comment: Yes thank you what a rookie mistake. I changed the Django version to 1.11 and all went smoothly from there.

Comment: glad to help you